# Not able to change and customize the title of UIButtons in a custom UITableViewCell during runtime

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains four `UIButtons`.  The text (titleLabel) for these buttons is generated based on the index of the cell.  I am customizing each button in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the following (answer1 is a `UIButton`)…

```
NSLog(@"Default button title: %@", myCustomCell.answer1.titleLabel.text);
[myCustomCell.answer1 setTitle:selectedQuestion.possibleAnswers[0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myCustomCell.answer1.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSLog(@"New button title: %@", myCustomCell.answer1.titleLabel.text);
[myCustomCell.answer1 adjustTitleFontSizeToFit];
```

Expected Output:

```
Default button title: Answer 1
New button title: *ANSWER TEXT HERE*
```

But the actual console output shows the string not updating, but on the device it is the correct string.  However, it sometimes does change the title, but only of the first button I create (I am using this same code on each button).

I created a category of `UIButton` with the `adjustTitleFontSizeToFit` method because I want the `titleLabel` of each button to auto size the font if the string doesn’t fit in the button frame.  When testing this method outside of this example, it works as expected.  The problem seems to be that the `titleLabel` of the button is not updating in time for `adjustTitleFontSizeToFit` to do it’s work.  In other words, when `adjustTitleFontSizeToFit` is called on the button, the string it operates on is the default string that is in the `xib` when I created the buttons.  An `NSLog` after `setTitle:forState:` also shows this.

The strange behavior (strange to me anyway) is that in app, it does actually change the title.  I just need to be able to work on the `titleLabel` during the cell building so I can resize the button label.

Any ideas are much appreciated and I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: What UI issue do you see? `adjustTitleFontSizeToFit` should act at render time, not call time.

Answer (score 0):

As with many UI bugs, the problem was a simple checkmark that was missed in my xib/storyboard.  I had the first button set as a 'custom' button type and the rest were set as system 'button' types.

[image: Set the button type!]

The give-away should have been that it was working for the one button, but not the others.  But in case anyone runs across a similar problem, I'll leave this up.

And if anyone needs to resize the font size of a UIButton, here is category method I used...

```
- (void)adjustTitleFontSizeToFit
{   
    UIFont *font = self.titleLabel.font;
    CGSize size = self.frame.size;

    for (CGFloat maxSize = self.titleLabel.font.pointSize; maxSize >= self.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor * self.titleLabel.font.pointSize; maxSize -= 1.f) {
        font = [font fontWithSize:maxSize];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [self.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        if(labelSize.height <= size.height) {
            self.titleLabel.font = font;
            [self setNeedsLayout];
            break;
        }
    }

    // set the font to the minimum size anyway
    self.titleLabel.font = font;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```